# How to find out if a default image is used in content?

Tags: 7, views, media

I have an Administration View for my content. I want to filter if a default image is used or if there is an already uploaded one.

I don't find a reference for this to use it as field and/or filter in views.

I tried the relationship for Content:Image, but this reveals nothing like "has default image" or something alike.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I now have a workaround for this. I added a field for the image as a mini-thumbnail, so a visual control if the default image is used is possible. The fields are in a table, so reverse sorting of the images reveals that all default-images come after custom images...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i added a filter criteria on photo:fid(photo is field name for image) not equal to the name of default image and it worked. i hope this will help you